# Get all the images from custom post type in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, portfolio

I am working on a portfolio WordPress theme and trying to grab and display every image in portfolio-single page.

I am using following code but its not working.

```
<div class="thumb">
   <?php 
   $args = array(
       'post_type' => 'attachment',
       'numberposts' => -1,
       'post_status' => 'any',
       'post_mime_type' => 'image',
       'post_parent' => $post->ID
   );

   $attachments = get_posts($args);
   if($attachments) : ?>
       <ul class="portfolio-image-list">
           <?php foreach ($attachments as $attachment) : ?>
           <li class="box">
               <figure>
                  <?php the_attachment_link($attachment->ID, true); ?>
               </figure>
            </li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
   <?php else: ?>
        <div class="box">
           <p>No images found for this post.</p>
       </div>
    <?php endif; ?>

</div>
```

Please help.

Comment: If you var_dump($attachments) is there anything in it?

Comment: No, its empty but it should not be. Is there anything wrong with the $args  array?

Comment: It's best to define a custom post type and taxonomy (portfolio and portfolio-category), and then in `WP_Query` add `'post-type' => 'portfolio'`, and pull all the info from the query.

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to retrieve a list of the posts rather than the attachments to the specific post in question. You'd instead need to retrieve the child objects of type 'attachment':

```
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'attachment',
  'posts_per_page' => -1,
  'post_status' => 'any',
  'post_mime_type' => 'image',
  'post_parent' => $post->ID
);

$attachments = get_children( $args );
```

But you can now use the 'get_attached_media' function to make this even easier. Try replacing the $attachments line with:

```
$attachments = get_attached_media( 'image', $post->ID );
```

If that still doesn't work, you can temporarily add `die($post->ID);` in your template and make sure that it's outputting the post ID correctly. If not, make sure you're running the code within The Loop so that $post->ID is available.

Comment: I can echo out post ID within the loop however its not working. $attachments returning an empty array.